# Why is Taking a Derivative of Quantities to a Negative Exponent an Application of the Chain Rule, Not the Power Rule

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

According to my calculus professor and MIT open coursework, taking the derivative of (x^2+4)^-1 is an application of the chain rule, not the power rule. The answer to the question is -(x^2+4)^-2, which makes sense to me, but I just don't understand why this is considered an application of the chain rule rather than the power rule, since the power rule says that d/dx(x^n) = nx^(n-1).

Here is a link to the MIT coursework I am talking about: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-a-definition-and-basic-rules/session-11-chain-rule/MIT18_01SCF10_ex11sol.pdf

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: The answer is not $-(x^2 + 4)^{-2}$. That's incorrect.

Comment: If by “power rule” you mean the formula that describes what you get when you differentiate a power of a function, I’m sure that the power rule does involve the chain rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Power Rule was applied, but so too was the chain rule, and also a few unmentioned others.

The power rule may only be applied when the derivation 'numerator' is a power of the 'denominator' , so first you must use the Chain Rule to obtain such.

Thus taking everything one elementary step at a time:

$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\mathrm d~(x^2+4)^{-1}}{\mathrm d~x}&=\dfrac{\mathrm d ~(x^2+4)^{-1}}{\mathrm d~(x^2+4)}\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm d~(x^2+4)}{\mathrm d~x}&&\text{Chain Rule}\\[2ex]&=-(x^2+4)^{-2}\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm d~(x^2+4)}{\mathrm d~x}&&\text{Power Rule}\\[2ex]&=-(x^2+4)^{-2}\cdot\left(\dfrac{\mathrm d~x^2}{\mathrm d~x}+\dfrac{\mathrm d~4}{\mathrm d~x}\right)&&\text{Additive Rule}\\[2ex]&=-(x^2+4)^{-2}\cdot\left(2x+\dfrac{\mathrm d~4}{\mathrm d~x}\right)&&\text{Power Rule }\\[2ex]&=-(x^2+4)^{-2}\cdot\left(2x+0\right)&&\text{Derivation of a Constant}\\[2ex]&= -2x(x^2+4)^{-2} &&\text{Algebraic Rearrangement}\end{align}$$

Comment: Why is d(x^2+4)^-1/d(x^2+4) = -(x^2+4)^-2?

Comment: The power rule.  Just substitute $(x^2+4)$ for $y$ in:  $$\dfrac{\mathrm d~y^{-1}}{\mathrm d~y~~~}=-y^{-2}\\~\\\dfrac{\mathrm d~(x^2+4)^{-1}}{\mathrm d~(x^2+4)~~~}=-(x^2+4)^{-2}$$

Comment: Isn't that for dy/dx, not dy/dy?

Comment: No, @UMA , the product rule is for $d y^n/dy$, $dz^m/dz$, and so forth.  Any variable term and any non-zero constant index may be used, as long as it fits the pattern.  It is a *schema*.$$\dfrac{\mathrm d z^m}{\mathrm d z}=m~z^{m-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

The derivative is $-2x(x^2+4)^{-2}$.  Thus the chain rule.  You missed $2x$.